ASP.NET Framework - System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll Publish Failure
I have this ASP.NET project running on .NET 4.8 called MyOTPWebService.
It resides in C:\Mypath\My_Projects\MyTiger
which is C:\Mypath\My_Projects\MyTiger\MyWebService
It builds fine, but when I tried to publish to:
C:\Users\myapp\Desktop\My_Deployments\MyOtp

I got this error:

Copying file packages\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.4.3.0\runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard1.6\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll to C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\MyWebService--676085791\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.4.3.0\runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard1.6\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll failed. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\MyWebService--676085791\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.4.3.0\runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard1.6\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll'.

Kindly help resolve the issue

What do you mean by "C:\Mypath\My_Projects\MyTiger which is C:\Mypath\My_Projects\ProjectTiger\MyWebService" ?

@Dai - This is the application name:   MyWebService
